# Move a line in a file from linenumber `n1` to linenumber `n2` in Unix

Tags: bash, file, shell, unix, sed

I have a file with name `file1` that looks as follows.

```
  1 intst
  2 1.0
  3 12.591870 0.000000 0.000000
  4 0.000000 12.591870 0.000000
  5 0.000000 0.000000 12.591870
  6 Ba Zr Al O
  7 27 26 1 81
  8 direct
  9 0.166667 0.166666 0.167762 Ba
 10 0.166667 0.166667 0.500000 Ba  #Line to be moved
 11 0.166666 0.166667 0.832238 Ba
 ...
 ...
 60 0.666668 0.666666 0.329117 Zr
 61 0.666665 0.666667 0.670884 Zr
 62 0.666667 0.666667 1.000000 Al #Moved line to be inserted below this line
 63 0.166667 0.999071 0.999999 O
```

I need to copy the contents of `line- 10` and move it below `line-62` by creating a new line so that the new filecontent appears as

```
  1 intst
  2 1.0
  3 12.591870 0.000000 0.000000
  4 0.000000 12.591870 0.000000
  5 0.000000 0.000000 12.591870
  6 Ba Zr Al O
  7 27 26 1 81
  8 direct
  9 0.166667 0.166666 0.167762 Ba
 10 0.166666 0.166667 0.832238 Ba #Original line- 11
 ...
 ...
 59 0.666668 0.666666 0.329117 Zr
 60 0.666665 0.666667 0.670884 Zr
 61 0.666667 0.666667 1.000000 Al
 62 0.166667 0.166667 0.500000 Ba #Original line-10
 63 0.166667 0.999071 0.999999 O
```

Using sed I separately know how to delete a line

```
sed -i.bkp -e '10d' file
```

and to insert a line

```
sed -i '10i <string>'file1
```

But I'm not sure how to copy contents of a line and move it to another line

Comment: @lurker Example suggests "move".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '10{h;D}; 62G' file
```

As per comment by @Benjamin, you can also use `d`.

```
sed '10{h;d}; 62G' file
```

Use `-i.bak` for in-place edit.

Here,

- `10 and 62` - Line number
- `h`  - Copy pattern space to hold space. This will save `line 10` to hold space.
- `G`  - Append hold space to pattern space. This will append `line 10` to pattern space.
- `D`  - Delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline.

Comment: Can you please explain how the options h, D and G works?

Comment: I delete my answer too similar to yours, but why not simply `sed '10h;62G' file` as the OP wants to copy the line, not to move it ?

Comment: @Kenavoz, `h` won't delete text from pattern space.

Comment: @Kenavoz If you look at the example given, the previous line 11 becomes line 10, so it's actually cut and paste, not copy and paste.

Comment: Could just as well use `d` here, no?

Comment: Yes. We can also use `d`.

Comment: @BenjaminW., Updated answer.

Comment: Fortunately the OP wants to move their line downwards.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in OS-X. Any suggestions as to how to make it work in OS-X

Comment: @WanderingMind, Try this : `sed -e '10{h;d};' -e '62G' file`

Answer (score 2):

awk:

```
awk -v n1=10 -v n2=62 '
    NR == n1 {line=$0; next}
    {print}
    NR == n2 {print line}
' file > file.new
```

or the venerable ed (edits the file in-place)

```bsh
ed file <<END_ED
# move line 10 after line 62
10m62
# save and quit
w
q
END_ED
```

Comment: The ed command can be "one-liner"ed in various ways, if that's important to you.